# Kubernetes namespace stuck in terminating status

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes namespace is stuck in terminating status.

This usually happens due to the finalizer

```
$ kubectl get ns
NAME             STATUS        AGE
cert-manager     Active        14d
custom-metrics   Terminating   7d
default          Active        222d
nfs-share        Active        15d
ingress-nginx    Active        103d
kube-public      Active        222d
kube-system      Active        222d
lb               Terminating   4d
monitoring       Terminating   6d
production       Active        221d
```

Answer (score 2):

### This worked for me :

kubectl get namespace linkerd -o json > linkerd.json

Where:/api/v1/namespaces/<your_namespace_here>/finalize

kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/linkerd/finalize" -f ./linkerd.json

Answer (score 1):

I have made this a script which is handy for me.

```
for i in $(kubectl get namespaces | grep "Terminating" | cut -d" " -f1)
do
 echo "deleting namespace $i"
 kubectl get namespace $i -o json |jq '.spec = {"finalizers":[]}' > tempfile.json
 kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/${i}/finalize" -f ./tempfile.json
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

`kubectl get namespace monitoring -o json > monitoring.json`

remove "kubernetes" from finalizers array.

`kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/finalize" -f ./monitoring.json`